# Is the connected sum of Hopf link with any knot a Torus link?

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, knot-invariants

The Hopf link is torus, but if I connect it with some arbitrary knot then what would the resulting link be? Is there some understanding of how it may relate to the class of the knot itself (torus/ hyperbolic/ satellite)? For example what if we take the connected sum of  Hopf link with the hyperbolic figure-8 knot?
[image]

The literature on classification of Knots is plentiful, but for multi-component (or even 2) Links  some references would be useful.